# TeXShop on MacOs El Captain - blurry pdf

Tags: texshop, viewers, rendering

I've recently updated to el captain OS, and the pdf viewer is coming up blurry. There are no issues if I open the pdf file in Preview directly, only the Preview pdf viewer in TexShop.

I have downloaded the latest version of MacTex.

EDIT: Below a picture with Preview on the right and TeXShop on the left.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot demonstrating the difference? Have you tried zooming in and out? Is it really blurry or just some sort of rendering bug thing?

Comment: You need to update TeXShop itself. The current version is 3.58, which, among other things, deals with the blurry PDF problem.

Comment: @sgmoye current version of texshop is 3.58

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: Let me elucidate: I had the fuzzy PDF problem with a slightly earlier version of TeXShop. The problem went away when I updated to the current version.

Comment: Oops! There was a small typo. I mean I have version 3.58, and the problem persists. The screen shot in the post is from this version.

Comment: In El Capitan, I get better results with "Preferences-->pdf-->Smooth test and line art" unchecked rather than checked.  Still, both Firefox and Chrome are giving me better results than Preview.  (Which you can get with 'open -a "Google Chrome" foo.pdf' from the command line.)

Answer (score 2):

First, on the right you are having Acrobat Reader (not Preview), which has its own PDF rendering package. If the left PDE was rendered using El Capitan's PDF rendering package (the same package that renders PDFs in OS X native Preview app) then it is highly likely you can do nothing about the quality because the PDF rendering package is not working very well in El Capitan. For this reason (Blurry PDFs in Preview in El Capitan) I rolled back to Yosemite.